# Upload client file to website through node

Tags: node.js

I'm trying to achieved the following:
Client has to fill a form and submit it to the node server
If client has a business card, snap a picture and it updates the form.

I have the API to translate image to json.
But I struggle to upload that image through node.

I created an html form with an input=file.
When input is changed, Ajax is called to upload that image.

On node, the request is received and basically transferred to that other website (camcard).
Json response should be sent back to client.

I just can't achieve that..

Any idea?

Here is some code. I do a post in 2 ways (regular and Ajax)
Html client:

```
<form method='POST' id="formCard"

        enctype='multipart/form-data'>

        <input type=file class="btn btn-outline-primary" name=upfile

            size=20 id="cardSelector" onChange="changeFile()">

    </form>   



    <form method='POST' action='/postCardPic'>

            Please specify a JPG file<br>

            <input type=file name=upfile size=20><br><br>

            <input type=submit value='Upload'>

        </form>

<script>

        function changeFile() {

            var formData = new FormData();

            formData.append( 'file', $( '#cardSelector' )[0].files[0] );

            $.ajax({

                data: formData,

                enctype: 'multipart/form-data',

                processData: false,

                contentType: false,

                type: "POST",

                url: "/postCardPic",

                success: function (response) { // on success..

                    console.log(response); // update the DIV

                },

                complete: function (data) {

                    hideLoader();

                }

            });

        }

    </script>
```

On the server side:

```
App.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({

      extended: false,

      limit: '50mb',

      parameterLimit:'50000'

    }));

    app.use(bodyParser.json({

      extended: false,

      limit: '50mb',

      parameterLimit:'50000'

    }));



    app.post('/postCardPic', function(req, response) {

  var urlCamCard='http://whatever.com'



//   var form = new Form();



//   form.parse(req, function(err, fields, files) {

//       res.writeHead(200, {'content-type': 'text/plain'});

//       res.write('received upload:\n\n');

//       res.end(util.inspect({fields: fields, files: files}));

//   });

//   form.on('file', function(name,file) {



//     //stream it to localhost:4000 with same name

//     fs.createReadStream(file.path).pipe(request.post(urlCamCard))



// });



  request.post({

    url:urlCamCard, form:req.body}, function optionalCallback(err, httpResponse, body) {

      if (err) {

        return console.error('upload failed:', err);

      }

      console.log('Upload successful!  Server responded with:', body);

    });

  response.end();

});
```

Log in both cases is the same:
Upload successful!  Server responded with: ErrorCode: -1 ErrorMsg: Image data size not supported

Comment: add code snippets of your ajax call and node endpoint

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution.
Here's is the code on the server side:

```
App.post("/postCardPic", function(req, res) {

  try {

    var form = new multiparty.Form();



    form.parse(req, function(err, fields, files) {});

    form.on("file", function(name, file) {

      var formData = {

        file: {

          value: fs.createReadStream(file.path),

          options: {

            filename: file.originalFilename

          }

        }

      };



      request.post(

        {

          url: theurl,

          formData: formData

        },

        function optionalCallback(err, httpResponse, body) {

          if (err) {

            return console.error("upload failed:", err);

          }

          res.end(body);

        }

      );

    });

  } catch (err) {

    console, log(err);

    res.end();

  }
```